# Updating the Oracle database through GET/ POST responses

Tags: oracle, api, postman

I am consuming a rest api through POSTMAN via "Get Product" and get the JSON formatted responses. Now I want to store them in my schema in the Oracle database. How would I go ahead? Please help me with any suggestions? Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a JSON table, and insert your response JSON there.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_JSON_TABLE (
  id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  json_data CLOB,
  CONSTRAINT my_json_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT json_chk CHECK (json_data IS JSON)
);
```